# Programatically modify Eclipse workspace and CDT options from a plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I want to modify an Eclipse workspace programatically from within a plugin (adding existing projects is my main request).
Also I want to modify CDT options (environment, indexer options) from within that plugin.

Does anyone know how to best do this or can point me to good documentations on that topic?

**EDIT:**
Actually I don't want to modify CDT project settings but some of the global CDT settings (actually I want to disable the indexer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends the kind of modification you are after.

For instance, adding a project is best illustrated by [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.tools.jdt/msg18827.html).

```
String theProjName = "Test";
String theLocation = "/some/test/project";

try {
    IWorkspaceRoot theRoot = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot();
    IProject theProject = theRoot.getProject(theProjName);
    IProjectDescription theDesc =       theProject.getWorkspace().newProjectDescription(theProjName);
        theDesc.setLocation(new Path(theLocation));
    theProject.create(theDesc, new NullProgressMonitor());
    if (theProject.exists()) {
        theProject.open(new NullProgressMonitor());
    }
} catch (CoreException err) {
    err.printStackTrace();
}
```

You could also want to [open an editor](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform/msg22481.html):

```
IWorkbenchWindow dw = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
try {
   if (dw != null) {
   IWorkbenchPage page = dw.getActivePage();
   if (page != null) {
    IDE.openEditor(page, file, true);                   
   }
}
} catch (PartInitException e) {

}
```

More generally, [eclipse.dev.org](http://www.google.fr/search?hl=fr&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&hs=igP&q=Programmatically+%22Eclipse+workspace%22+site%3Adev.eclipse.org&btnG=Rechercher&meta=) can be a good source for pointers on that topic.

---

Since 2004, [CDT has options](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/index.cgi/org.eclipse.cdt-build/org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.ui/ChangeLog?root=Tools_Project&view=co) you can modify through the [Preference Setting Store](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/cdt-dev/msg13563.html) (`ICSettingsStorage`). May be that can help.

---

Regarding the Indexer, beware of the [Discovery Preferences](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.tools.cdt/msg12192.html).
I am [not sure there is an Indexer API](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.tools.cdt/msg17721.html), but you may [look at the sources](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.tools.cdt/msg11153.html) for further clues.

Comment: Is it possible to mark answers as "half solutions"? Because your answer is good but I also need the CDT options part. But maybe I could remove the CDT part from my question and make a new one :-)
Do you see any chance you could add the CDT stuff?

Comment: @rstevens: The details are a bit foggy but one way to setup the CDT project settings is to create a New Project Wizard which extends the CDT one and add additional settings to the new CDT project (which could be importing existing projects into workspace I think). It can be a bit tricky to get everything in place though, it's been a while since I did something like that. If you want to edit/change the settings dynamically in the plug-in I suggest you extend the CDT preference page or something like that. It would probably give you access to the settings.

Comment: @rstevens: Sorry about the vague description but it's been a while and I'm not entirely sure what you're main objective is.

Comment: @rstevens: I will check the CDT part later today, but for now, my answer should certainly not be "selected" ;) May be someone will have a more complete post later on today.

Comment: @Subtwo & @VonC: Thank you for your responses. I edited the question because it was not clear enough. I want to edit global (workspace) CDT settings not project settings. Sorry for the unclear question.