# Eclipse workspace reference outside eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, workspace

I'm running the following code:

```
import org.eclipse.core.resources.IWorkspace;
import org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin;

public class WorkspaceTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IWorkspace workspace = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace();
    }
}
```

and I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Workspace is closed.
```

How can I get a reference to the workspace for a non-eclipse plugin?

(To be able to run the code here:)

http://www.ssw.uni-linz.ac.at/Teaching/Lectures/KompTech/JDT.pdf

Comment: I am also facing this problem now. How do u solve this problem then, care to share?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it can simply means you are not running under Eclipse but instead under just a standard Java application.

For an eclipse plugin, you need did to not call it too soon (like before creating workspace). Meaning for a non-eclipse plugin, you may have to somehow *create* a workspace, since you would not be able to reference the ones already present in eclipse.

Plus, you have to make sure you do not have `org.eclipse.core.resources` in the build path but rather as a dependent plugin in the plugin manifest.mf file. (see [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform/msg49860.html))
So the `ResourcePlugin` was not being instantiated by eclipse (although you could still have made calls to the `ResourcePlugin` class with the code).

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938439/programatically-modify-eclipse-workspace-and-cdt-options-from-a-plugin) for other ideas.

Comment: >Plus, you have to make sure you do not have...

Are you saying it can't be done outside a plugin? Or are you saying I need to find another way to instantiate the ResourcePlugin?

Comment: From what I have seen, it seems you have to access Workspace from within a plugin running within eclipse (and not as an independent Java application)

Comment: How do I run it as a plugin instead of a Java application?

Comment: You can run it as an "Eclipse Application"

Comment: Thanks. But how can I run this project here? http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-JavaCodeManipulation%5FAST/index.html (The link to download this project is under "Resources"[1]). After launching as an "Eclipse Application", I only see Eclipse opening up, I see nothing else.

Comment: There is a method in the class "public class ASTArticleActionDelegate implements IObjectActionDelegate"... It seems like run(...) is the starting point, can u tell what am I suppose to do to expect sth?

public void run(IAction action) {
  if (selection instanceof IStructuredSelection) {
   ICompilationUnit lwUnit = (ICompilationUnit) ((IStructuredSelection) selection)
     .getFirstElement();
   createActionExecutable(action.getId()).run(lwUnit);
  }
 }

Comment: I have oso posted my qn here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383139/running-an-eclipse-plugin
Urgent, thx...

Comment: Sorry yeeen, I just got back to my station today. I left you a detailed answer at your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383139/running-an-eclipse-plugin